# Computing [v]_s from the transition matrix for the given R^2 bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$ Let\:S\:=\:\left\{\left(6,3\right),\left(10,2\right)\right\}\:and\:T\:=\:\left\{\left(2,0\right),\left(3,2\right)\right\}\:be\:bases\:for\:\mathbb{R}^2 $$

$$ \left(note:\:v\:=\:\left(4,1\right)\:was\:given\:for\:\left[v\right]_T\right) $$

$$ Find\:the\:transition\:matrix P_{T\rightarrow S} $$

$$ Use\:these\:results\:to\:compute\:\left[v\right]_s $$

Okay, so this is the transition matrix I worked out:

$$\left[\begin{array}{c|c} S & T\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc|cc} 6 & 10 & 2 & 3 \\3 & 2 & 0 & 2\end{array}\right] \rightarrow \left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}1 & 0 & -\frac{2}{9} & \frac{7}{9} \\0 & 1 & \frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{12}\end{array}\right] $$

$$ P^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{2}{9} & \frac{7}{9} \\\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{12}\end{pmatrix} $$

This is where I'm stuck. Assuming that my transition matrix is correct, I don't know how to proceed in getting the coordinate matrix of S

$$ \left[v\right]_s $$

Comment: Your transisition matrix should be $2\times 2$ because it takes vectors in $\Bbb R^2$ to vectors in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @Bye_World it's an augmented matrix.

Comment: Oh.  Well either way, my solution works.  P.S. I edited your question.  That's how you should write augmented matrices.

Comment: Assuming your transition matrix is correct -- you just multiply your transistion matrix by the coordinates of $v$ wrt the $T$ basis.  That'll get you your coordinates wrt the $S$ basis.